# Is there a way to interact with pop-ups with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, puppeteer

I'm actually new to this, so any help is appreciated.
I'm building a bot with Puppeteer that interacts with Discord, using the screen share feature, but when clicking the screen share button, a pop-up appears to select which screen to share, and I really can't find its elements in the Chrome DevTools.

[image: the pop-up]

Is there a way I can work with this pop-up with Puppeteer ?